# Can i upload a file to my web app if i havent configure any backend in my app?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a landing-page. Its a form that sends an email with the users data. So far I have done everything with html, CSS, and JavaScript. Even sending the email.

My problem is when uploading a file. I want the user to be able to upload a reference. I've been searching and everything seems to need some sort of backend, with php or something like that... but I honestly don't know how to do that. Is there a way to simply resolve this matter with js?

here is my handleSubmit function:

```
const {register, handleSubmit} = useForm();

const onSubmit = () => {

    var emailMessage = {
        "Nombre" : document.getElementById('nombre').value,
        "Mensaje" : document.getElementById('mensaje').value


    } 
    
    const myForm = document.getElementById('form');

    window.Email.send({
        SecureToken: '------------************---------',
        To : 'blablablaexample@gmail.com',
        From : "blablablaeeee@gmail.com",
        Subject : document.getElementById('nombre').value,
        Body : emailMessage
    }).then(
      alert("Consulta enviada!")
    );

    myForm.reset();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need a backed to handle that.  Sending email is a big thing with lots of options.  You could spin up a node app to host this file then implement the sending of email on it.  You also need to right type of email account with credentials etc to be able to programatically use it to send emails on your behalf.  There are probably lots of 3rd party options out there, you should research them.